# Trying to concatenate Sass variable and a string

Tags: javascript, sass, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a Sass variable with a string. How do I do it?

Below there is a code example.

```
@mixin setIcons($pathImages:$pathImages, $extensionIcon:$extensionIcon {
   @each $class-icon in $class-icons-30 {
     .snw-tui-icon-#{$class-icon} {
       @include icon($class-icon, $pathImages, $extensionIcon, 30px);
   }
     .snw-tui-icon-**#{$class-icon} + "selected"** {
       @include icon(**$class-icon + "selected"**, $pathImages, $extensionIcon, 30px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to interpolate.

```
$sidebar-width: 20px;

.target {
     width: calc(100% - #{$sidebar-width});
}
```

Hope this helps

More info into it here: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-ever-need-to-know-about-sass-interpolation--cms-21375

Answer (score 4):

For a `font variable`, this is what worked for me:

```
$font-family-sans-serif:      -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol" !default;
$font-family-custom: 'My Custom Font', #{$font-family-sans-serif}
```

Good Luck

Comment: spent an hour looking for this `'My Custom Font', #{$font-family-sans-serif}` . Many thanks!